# how to cache response from endpoint in wso2 ESB

Tags: wso2, wso2-esb

I want to cache the response in my proxy and when i hit my proxy again then it should get me the cached data. I have tried using Cache mediator but am unable to find if my data is really getting cached or not.So basically what i am trying to achieve is if i have data in cache then it shouldn't hit the endpoint.It should send the response from cache. Looking forward to your answer. Thanks in advance

I have my service code as:

```
public class GetMirrorValue {
    public String getValue(String data) throws Exception {
    System.out.println("Inside Service code");
        return data;
    }
}
```

my inSequence is:

```
<sequence xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse" name="CheckCacheSeq">
   <cache scope="per-host" collector="false" hashGenerator="org.wso2.caching.digest.DOMHASHGenerator" timeout="20">
      <implementation type="memory" maxSize="100"/>
   </cache>
   <send>
      <endpoint key="DummyEP"/>
   </send>
</sequence>
```

and my out sequence is:

```
<outSequence xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse">
   <cache scope="per-host" collector="true"/>
   <send/>
</outSequence>
```

but whenever i hit my proxy service consecutively through try-it tool, i get data from service but not from cache coz every time in my server System.out.println("Inside Service code"); gets printed?

Answer (score 1):

You can modify your backend service (The endpoint invoked by proxy service), to print something in the server log, once a request got hit. First request should hit the backend. Then within the cached period, requests won't go to the backend service. It will go to backend service only after cache is expired. So looking at the print on the backend server log, you can observe the caching behavior.

http://docs.wso2.org/wiki/display/ESB460/Sample+420%3A+Simple+Cache+Implemented+on+ESB+for+the+Actual+Service

Comment: I followed the link. had done exactly the same steps but still i am getting the result described in above question

Comment: Add Log messages inside CheckCacheSeq, to verify that your requests are routed through CheckCacheSeq sequence (ex: Add two log messages before and after cache mediator). If the logs appear in carbon log, then try increasing timeout value for cache mediator.

Answer (score 0):

You can enable wirelogs in ESB to see the requests/responses going through ESB.